# ExtJS Drag and Drop - doesn't works. What is the function for this?

Tags: extjs, drag-and-drop

In my dropZone doesn't work onNodeDrop function!

notifyDrop works, but onNodeDrop - not. And my draggable element is restricted to put down to drop zone.

Answer (score 0):

The way to override a default drag and drop implementation in ExtJS is as follows:

```
v.dropZone = new Ext.dd.DropZone(v.getEl(), {

  // GetTarget
  getTargetFromEvent : function(e) {
    return {
      x : e.getX() - this.DDMInstance.deltaX,
      y : e.getY() - this.DDMInstance.deltaY
    };
  },

  // OnNodeOver
  onNodeOver : function(target, dd, e, data) {
    var rv = Ext.dd.DropZone.prototype.dropNotAllowed;
    if (data && data.selectedRecords.length == 0) {
      return Ext.dd.DropZone.prototype.dropNotAllowed;
    } else {
      rv = Ext.dd.DropZone.prototype.dropAllowed;

      Ext.Array.each(data.selectedRecords, function(selRec, index) {
        if (v.getStore().find('id', selRec.getId()) > -1) {
          rv = Ext.dd.DropZone.prototype.dropNotAllowed;
        }
      });
      return rv;
    }

  },

  // OnNodeDrop
  onNodeDrop : function(target, dd, e, data) {
    var dropValid = true;
    Ext.Array.each(data.selectedRecords, function(selRec, index) {
      if (v.getStore().find('id', selRec.getId()) == -1) {
        v.getStore().add(selRec);

        // set selection
        data.dataView.getSelectionModel().select(selRec.index);

      } else {
        dropValid = false;
      }
    });
    return dropValid;
  }
});
```

Where v is the dropzone (a gridpanel, dataview or any other component). As you can see, I have added some logic that disallows dropping the same item multiple times.